# Nested Array filter in AWS DynamoDB

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I'm new to NoSQL DynamoDB. Trying to build queries for a data model like this

```
{
        "versionName": "1997-edition1",
        "bookId": "47",
        "bookName": "myBookName",
        "chapters": [
            {
                "1": [
                    {
                        "1": "text for chapter 1  ",
                         
                    } 
                ],
                "2": [
                    {
                        "1": "text for chapter 2  " 
                    } 
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
```

I query the DB based on the versionName and the bookID. There is also a chapter input field, so I must fetch only the specific chapter. How can I achieve this ?

```
     TableName:  tableName,
      KeyConditionExpression: '#versionName = :versionReq   and #bookId =:bookReqId  ',
     ExpressionAttributeValues: { ':versionReq': req.apiGateway.event.queryStringParameters.version,
          ':bookReqId': req.apiGateway.event.queryStringParameters.bookId },
             ExpressionAttributeNames: { '#versionName': 'versionName',
       '#bookId':'bookId'  }
   }
```

version and bookId combination returns one row with all the chapters, but I want to return only the queried chapter. How can I include chapter here?

Comment: when you get the db result, just find and return the chapter by your logic code.

Comment: I had that in mind, but wanted to prevent fetching unwanted data from DB . Looks like that is the only solution for now, Thanks @hoangdv